# Using Google Service for iOS without using GoogleService-Info.plist

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin, google-analytics-sdk

I am able to use both Google SignIn and Analytics using GoogleService-Info.plist.

However, to reduce dependency, I want to move the information from the GoogleService-Info.plist into another .plist that contains my other information.

Would this be possible? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: DI is our everything :)
For now, due to my researching - we could not change the name, or make google SDK read from what we want. So I came up to [the next solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33336418/1040347)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can - both libraries allow you to configure them manually. You'll want to drop any references to `GGLContext`, and just setup the libraries directly:

```
[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = @"YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
```

and

```
[[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-XXXX-Y"];
```

You can check the reference docs for [Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/reference/) and [Sign In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/index) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. Do not initialise through pList , use instead manual setup using your keys and constants maintained in separate space in your project.

```
[[[GAI sharedInstance] logger] setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];
 id newTracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_KEY];
[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker = newTracker;
```