# How to merge Google configuration plist files in iOS when I am using GCM and firebase analytics

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

I am using GCM in my iOS app. Now I want to add Firebase analytics and Crash for the same project. How to keep / merge two Google configuration plist files in a single Xcode target. Plists have different api keys because one is for GCM and another one is for Firebase Analytics.

Comment: I think you can configure manually the GoogleService-Info.plist for this matter.
This SO question [Using Google Service for iOS without using GoogleService-Info.plist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32362471/), helps you to know how to configure manually the GoogleService-Info.plist. The other SO question that can help you are these SO question [33118889](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33118889) and [33403604](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33403604)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As suggested by Google I migrated to FCM by transferred my current GCM project to Firebase console and proceeded. Posting this to help others!